# How to generate RSA Public Key using modulus and exponent in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, rsa

I want to get RSA Public Key which is used for AWS authentication. I have a Kotlin Code but am unable to find a similar code in Swift. Here is the code for Kotlin.

Please let me know if anyone has an idea

Thanks!

Kotlin code

```
private fun getPublicKey(n: String, e: String): RSAPublicKey {
       val publicKeySpec = RSAPublicKeySpec(
              BigInteger(1, Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(n)),
              BigInteger(1, Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(e)),
       )
    
       return KeyFactory
             .getInstance("RSA")
             .generatePublic(publicKeySpec) as RSAPublicKey
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the right solution for that after many tries and attempts. I have copied the data extension from [Heimdall](https://github.com/henrinormak/Heimdall/blob/master/Heimdall/Heimdall.swift). It is helpful to combine modulus and exponent data.

Here is the complete code.

```
import Security

class RSAPublicKey {
    
    class func generateRSAPublicKey(modulus: String, exponent: String) -> SecKey? {
        guard let modulusData = Data(base64UrlEncoded: modulus) else {
            return nil
        }
        guard let exponentData = Data(base64UrlEncoded: exponent) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let publicKeyAttributes: [CFString: Any] = [
            kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
            kSecAttrKeyClass: kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
        ]
        
        var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
        
        let dataa = Data(modulus: modulusData, exponent: exponentData)
        
        guard let publicKey = SecKeyCreateWithData(dataa as CFData, publicKeyAttributes as CFDictionary, &error) else {
            if let error = error?.takeRetainedValue() {
                print("Failed to create RSA public key: \(error)")
            }
            return nil
        }
        var error1:Unmanaged<CFError>?
        if let cfdata = SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation(publicKey, &error1) {
            let data:Data = cfdata as Data
            let b64Key = data.base64EncodedString()
            print("Key =>", b64Key)
        }
        return publicKey
    }
    
    class func secKeyToData(_ publicKey: SecKey) -> Data? {
        var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
        
        guard let publicKeyData = SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation(publicKey, &error) as Data? else {
            if let error = error?.takeRetainedValue() {
                print("Failed to convert SecKey to data: \(error)")
            }
            return nil
        }
        return publicKeyData
    }
}


/// Encoding/Decoding lengths as octets
///
private extension NSInteger {
    func encodedOctets() -> [CUnsignedChar] {
        // Short form
        if self < 128 {
            return [CUnsignedChar(self)];
        }
        
        // Long form
        let i = Int(log2(Double(self)) / 8 + 1)
        var len = self
        var result: [CUnsignedChar] = [CUnsignedChar(i + 0x80)]
        
        for _ in 0..<i {
            result.insert(CUnsignedChar(len & 0xFF), at: 1)
            len = len >> 8
        }
        
        return result
    }
    
    init?(octetBytes: [CUnsignedChar], startIdx: inout NSInteger) {
        if octetBytes[startIdx] < 128 {
            // Short form
            self.init(octetBytes[startIdx])
            startIdx += 1
        } else {
            // Long form
            let octets = NSInteger(octetBytes[startIdx] as UInt8 - 128)
            
            if octets > octetBytes.count - startIdx {
                self.init(0)
                return nil
            }
            
            var result = UInt64(0)
            
            for j in 1...octets {
                result = (result << 8)
                result = result + UInt64(octetBytes[startIdx + j])
            }
            
            startIdx += 1 + octets
            self.init(result)
        }
    }
}

private extension Data {
    init(modulus: Data, exponent: Data) {
        // Make sure neither the modulus nor the exponent start with a null byte
        var modulusBytes = [CUnsignedChar](UnsafeBufferPointer<CUnsignedChar>(start: (modulus as NSData).bytes.bindMemory(to: CUnsignedChar.self, capacity: modulus.count), count: modulus.count / MemoryLayout<CUnsignedChar>.size))
        let exponentBytes = [CUnsignedChar](UnsafeBufferPointer<CUnsignedChar>(start: (exponent as NSData).bytes.bindMemory(to: CUnsignedChar.self, capacity: exponent.count), count: exponent.count / MemoryLayout<CUnsignedChar>.size))
        
        // Make sure modulus starts with a 0x00
        if let prefix = modulusBytes.first , prefix != 0x00 {
            modulusBytes.insert(0x00, at: 0)
        }
        
        // Lengths
        let modulusLengthOctets = modulusBytes.count.encodedOctets()
        let exponentLengthOctets = exponentBytes.count.encodedOctets()
        
        // Total length is the sum of components + types
        let totalLengthOctets = (modulusLengthOctets.count + modulusBytes.count + exponentLengthOctets.count + exponentBytes.count + 2).encodedOctets()
        
        // Combine the two sets of data into a single container
        var builder: [CUnsignedChar] = []
        let data = NSMutableData()
        
        // Container type and size
        builder.append(0x30)
        builder.append(contentsOf: totalLengthOctets)
        data.append(builder, length: builder.count)
        builder.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        
        // Modulus
        builder.append(0x02)
        builder.append(contentsOf: modulusLengthOctets)
        data.append(builder, length: builder.count)
        builder.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        data.append(modulusBytes, length: modulusBytes.count)
        
        // Exponent
        builder.append(0x02)
        builder.append(contentsOf: exponentLengthOctets)
        data.append(builder, length: builder.count)
        data.append(exponentBytes, length: exponentBytes.count)
        
        self.init(bytes: data.bytes, count: data.length)
    }
}

extension Data {
    init?(base64UrlEncoded: String) {
        var base64Encoded = base64UrlEncoded
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "+")
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: "/")

        let paddingLength = 4 - base64Encoded.count % 4
        if paddingLength < 4 {
            base64Encoded += String(repeating: "=", count: paddingLength)
        }

        self.init(base64Encoded: base64Encoded)
    }
}
```

Example:

```
 if let rsakey = RSAPublicKey.generateRSAPublicKey(modulus: "3bmGZLQSl3-wvGZVrZeI-HGz0XjB6F1lcwyxGRNl4GN3c7qHJyK5EiTqBNHKCQ76njmbERvIph8NlrH4G5l8tWUbB5z3vQYBkegc-fK0q7-QAZMJ9GglxjbppeIHpvYlk5G04CNedzyxA4SG2KNPdELgXYZDOVKtmd2jSSVys1P81H7olm1TS_3jTZP9PScY0t0fOibzzOFK7pdpfz6yjMt2FMLwMtLYNcZ2QaBRqFntNZ5biDiSsk60M5f_DwwAAKnDMZ5pT0qDeFMo8JQfhGMhr8a46oNXXbRmLXGUEytbiesQPVaTMpDkWqyxq_pOFhn2Er99i698YS6LNuZpeQ", exponent: "AQAB") {
       print("Key", rsakey)
 }
```

Output:

```
Key <SecKeyRef algorithm id: 1, key type: RSAPublicKey, version: 4, block size: 2048 bits, exponent: {hex: 10001, decimal: 65537}, modulus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addr: 0x281877d60>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this in some of my projects, check it please.

```
import Foundation
import Security

func getPublicKey(n: String, e: String) throws -> SecKey {
guard let nData = Data(base64Encoded: n),
      let eData = Data(base64Encoded: e) else {
    throw NSError(domain: "Error", code: -1, userInfo: nil)
}

let attributes: [CFString: Any] = [
    kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
    kSecAttrKeyClass: kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
    kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: 2048,
]

var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
guard let key = SecKeyCreateWithData(Data() as CFData,
                                     attributes as CFDictionary,
                                     &error) else {
    throw error!.takeRetainedValue() as Error
}

let addParams: [CFString: Any] = [
    kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
    kSecAttrKeyClass: kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
    kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: 2048,
    kSecAttrIsPermanent: false,
]

let publicKeyData = Data([UInt8](nData) + [UInt8](eData))

guard let publicKey = SecKeyCreateWithData(publicKeyData as CFData,
                                           addParams as CFDictionary,
                                           &error) else {
    throw error!.takeRetainedValue() as Error
}

return publicKey 
}
```

Comment: It is throwing an error "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -50 - RSA public key creation from data failed)"